# What msbuild reserved types/variables already exist for use in a .csproj?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

In my .csproj file there are some...shortcuts? System Variables? for certain things.
Like this (found near the top of the file):

```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```

But there seem to be more options like the $(Configuration) and $(Platform).
I've found the following in my file:

```
@(MainAssembly)
@(_DebugSymbolsOutputPath)
$(MSBuildToolsPath)
$(OutDir)
$(CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory)
$(ProjectDir)
$(_DebugSymbolsProduced)
$(SkipCopyBuildProduct)
$(Platform)
$(Configuration)
```

I don't want to make my own variables or anything like that, I just want to know what reserved types already exist for use.

**EDIT** I Found the answer I was looking for, it was in Microsoft.Build.CommonTypes.xsd
It contains things like this.

Comment: These are MSBuild properties. Some are pre-defined and you can define your own. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx

Comment: The direct link didn't help out at all. But I was able to find this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388%28v=vs.100%29.aspx from that, so thanks I guess.

Comment: See [Inside the Microsoft® Build Engine: Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft-Build-Engine-Foundation/dp/0735645248/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1374253502&sr=8-2&keywords=msbuild)

Comment: Rephrased the question to better reflect the answer I was looking for: It was contained in Microsoft.Build.CommonTypes.xsd

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing here are called MsBuild properties.  It's easiest to think of MsBuild as a scripting language for build and these as variables in that language.  Like variables in any language the user is free to introduce new ones hence there is no real concept of "all the valid commands".  Users can define more hence the set of valid commands is virtually infinite

There are a number of well known and reserved properties though.  This may be what you are looking for

> [MSbuild Reserved and Well Known Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx)

Comment: No, those aren't what I was looking for. I found them though, I found this file Microsoft.Build.CommonTypes.xsd. That has the element names, and what their attributes and types are. That's what I was looking for. I'll have to rephrase my question to reflect this. Thanks for trying though!